# How to display my root_url on a page as "example.com" rather than "http://example.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to achieve this url on my users profile in a cleaner way:
Profile Address: localhost:3000/username

This is how I do it:
`<%= link_to "localhost:3000#{root_path}#{@user.username}", @user.username %>`

Quite an ugly way to do it. I could store the url I want in a variable in a helper or controller or something e.g. shortened_root_url = localhost:3000/ (or site name) and there are other ways I could do it ...

**But isn't there a way I could just use root_url and have some magic remove the http:// from the url when displaying on users profile?**

NOTE:
I'm talking about the URL displayed to the user on his/her page, **not** in the href attr of an anchor tag.

Comment: A url must start with a scheme. `http` is a scheme.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not necessarily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181207/is-it-safe-to-use-schemeless-protocol-uris-on-public-websites-ex-www-examp

Comment: Aha, I forgot about that! In any event, we were all confused about what the OP wanted. Now we see that it's just a text version of a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is unusual, really... so there probably isn't a direct way of doing it.

you can look into the "url_for" options to see what would be most applicable. 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for

It has options like "protocol" or "path_only" that might help you build what you need.

For your needs, if all you're doing is removing the protocol, why not just create the full url and use gsub eg:

```
link_to @user.username, username_url(:username => @user.username).gsub("http://", '')
```

You'd also need an appropriate route. I've just guessed at your routing here, but say in Rails 2.3.X you'd have something like:

```
map.username '/:username', :controller => :users, :action => :show
```

Comment: I guess the easier way I can do it right now then is to store the root url address "mysite.com" in a variable and just call that instead.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. You can create the whole url using the url_for method (or creating a proper, named url) then just remove the http bit using string-logic (ie gsub). I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Profile Address: <%= link_to root_url(:user => @user.username).gsub("http://", ''), @user.username  %>    that is close to what I want. URL shows on page without http:// but the url is not shown the way I want it.It shows localhost:3000/?user=username   instead of localhost:3000/username

Comment: That just means you need to set up a proper route for this url. have added an eg to the answer.

Comment: You just want to display the path generated from the route on the page, but leave off the "http://". You don't need `link_to`, just insert the modified path into your page: `<%= username_url(@user).gsub('http://','') %>`

Comment: That's what i said... but there was confusion about how it worked, so I decided to put  route in to be explicit :)